# Stuck with the number pattern printing in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, logic

Stuck with the number pattern printing logic. Let me know what i am doing wrong as my file is simply going on execution without giving me a pattern.

My Code --

```
<?php

$num = 4;

for( $j=1 ; $j <= $num ; $j++ )
{
    for( $i=$j ; $i < $num-1 ; $i++ )
    {
    echo "&nbsp;";
    }

    for( $j ; $j >= 1 ; $j-- )
    {
    echo $j."&nbsp;";
    }

echo "<br />";
}
```

Pattern to achieve --

```
   1
  21
 321
4321
```

**UPDATE**

After applying new changes following are the screenshots ---

[image: On STAR USEAGE]

[image: ON BLANK USAGE]

Comment: Kindly specify the logical error im doing in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the last `for`, that should not exist since you are already looping.

And create a new variable which will hold the printed text for the next increment.

```
<?php

$num = 4;
$wrap = '';

for( $j=1 ; $j <= $num ; $j++ )
{
    for( $i=$j ; $i < $num ; $i++ )
    {
        echo "&nbsp; ";
    }

    echo $wrap = $j.$wrap;
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: @MihaiLorga please check my updated post with screenshot ..blank spaces are not placing correctly –

Comment: @MihaiLorga Awesome its working ..but how lol ??? what actually is the problem with blank spaces????

Comment: NBSP stands for `No-break space.`, `&nbsp;` + `(space)` is the key

Comment: @Mihailorga Thx for all the info u provided ..really g8 :)

Answer (score 5):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  echo str_pad(implode('', range($i, 1)), 4, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br />';
}
```

Right aligned using CSS

```
echo '<div style="text-align:right;">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  echo implode('', range($i, 1)) . '<br />';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: +1 for the str_pad method, could you please tell me what is wrong in the above code ..to help me to build my logic :)

Comment: I guess it's because you use `$j` for the outer and the second inner loop.

Comment: I don't think will result his expectation.

Comment: @MihaiIorga you are right its not printing in the right order check my updated post

Comment: @KingCrunch please check my updated post with screenshot ..blank spaces are not placing correctly

Comment: @swapnesh They are placed correctly, but I guess you execute it in your browser? Depending on what this is good for I recommend the `text-align`-css-property, but you can `str_replace(' ', '$nbsp;', $string)` too (if you like, but alignment is not what the fixed-length whitespaces meant to be used for).

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental reason is that a browser wont render multiple spaces only the first one, you can overcome this by using the non breaking space html entity `&nbsp` in place of spaces.

Soooo, If you want your actual pattern to look like:

```
   1
  21
 321
4321
```

And not like:

```
1
21
321
4321
```

Use `&nbsp` (Edit: Tho actually use `&nbsp;[space]` as just 1 seems to not compensate for the width of the `1` char vs `4`)

```
<?php 
    $num = 4;
    $result = array();
    foreach(range($num,1) as $i){
        $result[] = str_repeat('&nbsp; ',$num-$i).implode('',range($i,1)).'<br />';
    }
    echo implode('',array_reverse($result));
?>
```

Or you could use a `<pre>` tag like:

```
<?php 
$num = 4;
$result = array();
foreach(range($num,1) as $i){
    $result[] = str_repeat(' ',$num-$i).implode('',range($i,1)).PHP_EOL;
}
echo '<pre>'.implode('',array_reverse($result)).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Wow .. you actually add `<pre>` tag in your HTML applications?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone..its working what was actually the problem with the blank spaces???

Comment: that should be `str_repeat('&nbsp; ',$num-$i)` with a space. and you are not answering his question. `Kindly specify the logical error im doing in my code`

Answer (score 1):

As it is right now, the problem lies in your third (or second nested) `for` loop.

You can't just reuse `$j` as a counter here, since `$j` is still being actively used in the encompassing for loop. Substitute that for loop with:

```
for( $k = $j ; $k >= 1 ; $k-- )
{
    echo $k."&nbsp;";
}
```

Comment: please check my updated post with screenshot ..blank spaces are not placing correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your program, You can go to [Develepor hell](http://developerhell.blogspot.in/2014/01/number-pattern.html) for more such pattern

// Outer look for line change

for ($i = 1; $i<=5; $i++) {

```
// Loop added for spacing
for ($s = $i; $s<=10-$i; $s++) {
    echo "&nbsp;";
    }

// Inner loop for printing required pattern
for ($j = $i; $j>=1; $j--) {
    echo $j;
}

echo '</br>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here is the code for your program,
// Pattern - 1

$num = 4;

// to print no. of rows
for( $i=1 ; $i <= $num ; $i++ )
{

    
    // To print white space
    for( $j=1 ; $j <= $num-$i ; $j++ )
    {
        echo "0";
    }
    
    // To print pattern
    for( $z= $i ; $z>=1 ; $z-- )
    {
        
        echo $z;
    }
    
    
    // To print new line
    echo "<br />";
}

==>> Output
0001
0021
0321
4321

//===================================================================//

Pattern - 2

$z=1;
$n=3;

# no of rows
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
# to check even or odd
if($i%2 == 0)
{
    # main logic to display in reverse order // right to left
    $z = ($z+$n) -1;

    $a = $z;
    for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
    {
        echo $z--;
    }

    $z = $a+1;


}
else
{
    # display data left to right

    for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
    {
        echo $z++;
    }
}

echo "<br/>";

}

==>> Output
123
654
789
```

Comment: Thats a lot of code! Any chance you could add a paragraph to explain this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be that you are printing your output into an HTML document which condenses multiple spaces as its default behavior. See "[Why does HTML require that multiple spaces show up as a single space in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433493/2943403)" To "preserve" whitespaces while printing, use the `<pre>` tag.

I'll add a math-based solution instead of multiple iterated function calls and multiple loops (inspired by [my explained answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023959/2943403)).  Once your number limit gets higher than 9, I don't know if my output will align with your desired output.

Effectively, I use `printf()` to left-pad every line with spaces to the same max length.  Each successive number prints the integer as many times as its value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qMSQf))

```
$num = 4;
echo "<pre>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; ++$i) {
    printf("% {$num}d<br>", (10 ** $i - 1) / 9 * $i);
}
```

HTML Output (click on the eye icon in the demo link to switch to HTML mode):

```
   1
  22
 333
4444
```

For comparison these also work inside of the `for()` loop (and offer a more intuitive result above 9):

```
printf("% {$num}d<br>", str_repeat($i, $i));
```

Or

```
echo str_repeat(' ', $num - $i) . str_repeat($i, $i) . "<br>";
```