# generating same number with the given length

Tags: php, math, integer, repeat

I have this math assignment that I should make into code.
I've tried all I thought of but I couldn't find a solution.
All this should be done without using php functions, only math operations.
You can use while, for, and such...

So I have number for example `9`
Now I should create number of the length `9` which would be `999999999`

If I had, for example, number `3`, then the result should be `333`.

Any ideas?

```
$gen = -1;
while($highest > 0) {
    $gen = $highest + ($highest * 10);
    $highest = $highest - 1;
}

echo $gen;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? do some effort and show some code. this platform is not a free source code provider. your assignment is only two lines of code. do some effort otherwise you will not become a software developer

Comment: Yes I have! There is some code I used. Results I got were 99, 33 but thats not what it should be.

Comment: Is this supposed to be math generated number or just make the number? The most obvious is strpad, but I guess you don't want that? What happens if input is 0?

Comment: If you can accept "string math", this is probably the shortest and fastest code; https://3v4l.org/m3SEQ

Comment: @Andreas my first thought was `str_repeat()`.  `echo (int)str_repeat($n,$n);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method that does not build a string; it uses pure math.  (There will be many, many ways to do this task)

```
$x=9;
$result=0;
for($i=$x; $i; --$i){         // this looping expression can be structured however you wish potato-potatoe
   $result+=$x*(10**($i-1));  // x times (10 to the power of (i-1))
}
echo $result;
// 999999999
```

*note: `**` acts like `pow()` if you want to look it up.

---

Late edit:  here is a clever, little loopless method (quietly proud).  I am only calling `range()` and `foreach()` to demo; it is not an integral component of my method.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/GIjfG

```
foreach(range(0,9) as $n){
    // echo "$n -> ",(integer)(1/9*$n*(10**$n)-($n/10)),"\n";
    // echo "$n -> ",(1/9*$n*(10**$n)-(1/9*$n)),"\n";
    // echo "$n -> ",(int)(1/9*10**$n)*$n,"\n";
    // echo "$n -> ",(int)(10**$n/9)*$n,"\n";
    echo "$n -> ",(10**$n-1)/9*$n,"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 22
3 -> 333
4 -> 4444
5 -> 55555
6 -> 666666
7 -> 7777777
8 -> 88888888
9 -> 999999999
```

`1/9` is the hero of this method because it generates `.111111111`(repeating).  From this float number, I am using `10**$n` to "shift" just enough `1`s to the left side of the decimal point, then multiplying this float number by `$n`, then the float must be converted to an integer to complete.

Per @axiac's comment, the new hero is `10**$n-1` which generates a series of nines to the desired length (no float numbers).  Next divide the nines by nine to generate a series of ones which becomes the perfect multiplier.  Finally, multiply the series of ones and the input number to arrive at the desired output.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. This is math. not string building.

Comment: `**` is available only on PHP 5.6 and newer versions.

Comment: @axiac you are welcome to upgrade your version if it doesn't work for your environment.  Look, I quickly mocked that up from my phone.   I think it provides correct results.  Certainly this is not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: In my opinion, if OP does not specifically write what version he/she uses then it's OPs problem to convert functions. If OP says "I use PHP 4" then it would be bad to write an answer suited for PHP 7. In short, my opinion is a downvote for PHP version is not correct. A comment, sure. But downvote is a bit too much.

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you @mickmackusa

Comment: @Cadilab I've added a loopless solution...  You may or may not be the "cool kid" tomorrow at school when you reveal this newer method.

Comment: I might still refine my method when I get more time.

Comment: `(10**$n-1)/9*$n` and you don't need to cast to `int` any more.

Answer (score 3):

There are two operations you need to accomplish:

1. given a number `$number`, append the digit `$n` to it;
2. repeat operation #1 some number of times (`$n` times).

Operation #1 is easy:

```
$number = $number * 10 + $n;
```

Operation #2 is even easier:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i ++)
```

**What else do you need?**
Initialization of the variable used to store the computed number:

```
$number = 0;
```

Put them in order and you get:

```
// The input digit
// It gives the length of the computed number
// and also its digits
$n = 8;

// The number we compute
$number = 0;

// Put the digit $n at the end of $number, $n times
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i ++) {
    $number = $number * 10 + $n;
}

// That's all
```

Answer (score 2):

If `intval()` is accepted:

```
$result = '';
$input = 9;
for($i=0; $i < $input; $i++){
    $result .= $input;
}
$result = intval($result);
```

else:

```
$result = 0;
$input = 9;
for($i=0; $i < $input; $i++){
    $factor = 1;
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
        $factor *= 10;
    }
    $result += $input * $factor;
}
```

=>
9 + 90 + 900 + 9000 + 90000...

Comment: Why do you need two loops?

Comment: Could be replaced by the ** / pow()-function like mickmackusa did

Comment: You can also just cast the string to integer by putting `(int)` or `(integer)` in front of `$result` after the loop.