# PHP: explode(' ',$string); re-inserts removed blank space

Tags: php, get, preg-replace, explode

`$_GET['search']` imports the following string: "`first second \ \ third`" (the spaces between "second" and "third" are just blank spaces, the slashes are added since SO's text area does not allow multiple consecutive blank spaces).

The following script is then to process the imported string:

```
$searchString = $_GET['search'];
$searchString = preg_replace('/(\W)(\S)(\s+)/', '', $searchString);
echo $searchString . ' ';
print_r( explode(' ', $searchString) );
```

Which, strangely, results in:

```
first second third Array ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => [3] => [4] => third )
```

I.e. the blank spaces are removed, as anticipated, from `$searchString` when `echo`ing it, but PHP's `explode` seems to "re-insert" them. How can this be?

Comment: I'm not convinced that what you're "seeing" is what's actually happening. What do you see if you `echo $searchString` *before* you do the `preg_replace`? (Bear in mind that multiple consecutive spaces in an HTML document are [typically rendered as a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser).)

Comment: @Matt Gibson Exactly the same results, blank spaces removed.

Comment: Yes. Which means that the preg_replace isn't actually doing what you think it's doing. It's your browser that is condensing the multiple spaces down to a single space when it's showing you the output. They're there from start to finish, which is why `explode` is still finding them.

Comment: Makes sense... I'll tick it as 'correct answer' if you'll post it as one!

Comment: I think Scott's answer sums things up nicely. I'd just accept that one.

Comment: True. It just came in. I'll do that. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: When you're testing stuff like this in the browser, wrap the string in <pre> tags so the whitespace is more visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your regex is doing what you think. Or maybe you should explain what it's supposed to be doing. If you want to remove multiple spaces, use this:

```
$searchString = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $searchString);
```

Comment: Works excellent! Thanks for the help. I'll tick correct as soon as the system allows for it!

Answer (score 4):

An easy fix is to use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty array values:

```
$new_array = array_filter(explode(' ', $searchString));
```