# Html.fromHTML removes double space

Tags: android

Maybe this isn't a bug since the documentation doesn't say much about what `fromHTML()` exactly does, but it's a problem for me nonetheless. If the provided string contains two or more spaces in sequence, `fromHTML()` removes all but one:

```
Html.fromHtml("Test   123").toString()
     (java.lang.String) Test 123
```

If I replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` it seems to behave as expected, but causes me grief in other parts of my program:

```
Html.fromHtml("Test&nbsp;&nbsp;123").toString()
     (java.lang.String) Test  123
```

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how HTML normally handles rendering of whitespace.

From the [HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#whitespace) (**emphasis** mine):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source
>   document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word
>   spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). **In particular, user
>   agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing
>   output inter-word space.** This can and should be done even in the
>   absence of language information

The goal of the `fromHtml` function is to visually render the text based on the contained HTML, so it makes sense that it will follow HTML rendering rules as closely as possible.

If you'd like to preserve white space exactly, you could see if `fromHtml()` supports the `<pre>` tag?

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is because that's how Html behaves.

Do something like this:

```
String myText = "Test   123";
Html.fromHtml(myText.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")).toString()
```

This way, it preserves the original value of your string.

Comment: The original value is " "(blank space character) where as Html.fromHtml(myText.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")).toString() converts it to &nbsp; . when i try to re-replace "&nbsp;" to " " I still got the newer string where the space character was not " "(blank space character) but a "&nbsp;". So any work around you know for this issue?

Comment: this make a problem about tags which have space like <Font Color.. and ignores this styles.

Answer (score 2):

**Best approach works for me 100%**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311464/2652368) answer works but cause side effect on some tag styles like `<font color=#FFFFFF>Text</font>`

To solve this problem just ignore one spaces with this way:

```
// htmlText = "This    is test";
public String fixDoubleSpaceIssue(String htmlText)
{
    htmlText= text.replace("   ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    htmlText= text.replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    return htmlText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as `Html.fromHtml` uses the same rules that a browser uses to parse the HTML, yes, it is expected that multiple spaces are collapsed into one as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser) and [any other HTML reference](http://www.unm.edu/~tbeach/examples/Text.html).

Answer (score -3):

I used the following and it worked!

`myText = myText.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); 
 myText = Html.fromHtml(myText).toString(); 
 myText = myText.replaceAll("%20", " ");`