# How can I display some text with spaces in HTML, with double space characters

Tags: html

I need to display the following as HTML text (verbatim):

```
T H I S  I S  A  T E X T
```

As you can see:

- all characters have a space in between
- the space characters have been **doubled**
- I want to have that inside an `<a>` tag

What I have tried is:

```
<a href="#">T H I S  I S  A  T E X T</a>
```

But html compresses several space characters into one.

How can I force the double spaces?

Comment: I learned something new today  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser

Comment: Is the goal to actually have a space character between every printing character or just spread out the letters?

Comment: using &nbsp is not good as i guess .You can use letter spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**letter-spacing**

Definition and Usage

The letter-spacing property increases or decreases the space between characters in a text.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    a {letter-spacing:5px;}

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a href="#">THIS IS A TEXT</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/x4hDa/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via CSS

```
letter-spacing: 5px;
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution than &nbsp which is non-breaking, is &emsp which is double space (useful at the end of a sentence), or &ensp which is single space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML **pre** tag and style it e.g.

```
<a href="#"><pre>T H I S  I S  A  T E X T</pre></a>
```

**pre** tag preserve any number of spaces in HTML. You can also style it to look like regular text e.g.

```
<style>
    pre {
         background: transparent;
         display: inline;
         border: none;
         padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a **Non-breaking Space** caracter `$nbsp;`... It's one of **HTML Entities** avaible out there ;-)

More Info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` between your letters like this:
       `T&nbsp;H&nbsp;I&nbsp;S&nbsp;&nbsp;I&nbsp;S&nbsp;&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;T&nbsp;E&nbsp;X&nbsp;T`

Answer (score 0):

Use the style `white-space: pre:`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <span style="white-space: pre">    Extra   Space   </span>
  <br>
  <span>    No    Extra   Space   </span>
</html>
```