# Concatenated white space does not display in result

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation, whitespace

The padding I want is not properly concatenating, i.e. the white spaces are not showing up. Not sure why it isn't showing up and have been at it for a couple hours tweaking the code with no solution in sight.

```
var padWord = function(word){
    if(endsInPunctuation(word)){
        trueLength = (word.length)-1;
    }else{
        trueLength = word.length;
    }
    switch(trueLength){
        case 1:
            word = "   " + word.fontcolor("red");
            break;
        case 2:
            word = "  " + word.replaceAt(1, word.charAt(1), "red");
            break;
        case 3:
            word = "  " + word.replaceAt(1, word.charAt(1), "red");
            break;
```

Comment: Did you debug your code, put some `console.log` statements somewhere and see which values you got?

Comment: This is the just way HTML works. It compacts multiple spaces down to a single space. To work around it use `&nbsp;` instead of each space. For more information on why HTML does this see [Why do multiple spaces in an HTML file show up as single spaces in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browsers collapse more than one whitespace character by default. Use nonbreaking spaces `&nbsp;` or css `white-space:pre;` or the html tag `<pre>`

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the string concatenation. The spaces *are* getting added to the string. The problem is in how you're displaying the result. In most cases, whitespace around content is collapsed in HTML elements. There are a few ways to get around this.

1. Use CSS to override the default behavior of the HTML element by adding this line to the CSS:

   ```
   #screen{
       ...
       white-space: pre;
   }
   ```
2. Convert the spaces to html entities which will be displayed. Change this:

   ```
   textShow.innerHTML = word;
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   textShow.innerHTML = word.replace(/\s+/, function(s) {
       return s.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
   });
   ```

Comment: That helps with the spacing but eliminates the red-highlighted letter.