# JQuery copy input value with multiple spaces inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying is if a user has entered a value with multiple spaces I want them to copy it to a span. But the issues is `span` eliminates all spaces. So how can I achieve this functionality.

What I have tried;

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/8numkeuu/)

**Html**

```
<span class="span"></span><br>
<input  type="text" value="1               1" />
```

**CSS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputVal = $('input').val();
    $('.span').text(inputVal);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

css

```
.span {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputVal = $('input').val();
    $('.span').text(inputVal);
});
```

```css
.span {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span"></span><br>
<input  type="text" value="1               1" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8numkeuu/14/

Answer (score 2):

Browser will trim double spaces by default, so you won't see them render.

You will need to replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` and you will get the desired results.

```
$(".span").html(inputVal.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;"));
```

This code just replaces all the spaces with `&nbsp;` and it works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8numkeuu/12/

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre></pre>` tag into your span.

Because HTML doesn't show spaces on front end without `pre` tag.

Your code is correct and getting values with space

check here:

HTML:

```
<span class="span"><pre></pre></span><br>
<input  type="text" value="1               1" />
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputVal = $('input').val();
    $('.span pre').text(inputVal);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8numkeuu/11/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputVal = $('input').val();

    $('.span').html("<pre>"+inputVal+"<pre>");
});
```

This code is tested on Fiddle.

Comment: Preformatted text between the start and end PRE tag is rendered using a fixed with font, in addition whitespace characters are treated literally. The spacing and line breaks are rendered directly, unlike other elements, for which repeated whitespace chararacters are collapsed to a single space character and line breaks introduced automatically.

Comment: Here is the Example 

<PRE>
       Higher still and higher
         From the earth thou springest
       Like a cloud of fire;
         The blue deep thou wingest,
And singing still dost soar, and soaring ever singest.</PRE>
which is rendered as:
       Higher still and higher
         From the earth thou springest
       Like a cloud of fire;
         The blue deep thou wingest,
And singing still dost soar, and soaring ever singest.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Why do multiple spaces in an HTML file show up as single spaces in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser) for better understanding

Replacing spaces with &nbsp will resolve the issue.