# string.repeat tab/whitespace not working in span

Tags: javascript, string, repeat

I am now trying to add whitespaces for the 'child' table rows with string.repeat, however, in my `span` elements, it doesn't work though it works in `textareas`.

This is my HTML:

```
<span id="first"></span>
<span id="second"></span>
<span id="third"></span>
```

This is my JS:

```
$('#first').append('Help');
$('#second').append('   '.repeat(4) + 'Help');
$('#third').append(' '.repeat(4) + 'Help');
```

Link to jsfiddle with `spans`:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/mbzjedxr/

Link to same code but `textareas` except of `spans`:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/mbzjedxr/1/

Why doesn't it work on spans and is there any way to make it work?

Comment: [Permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) for `span` might shed some light on your issue. "... plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple spaces in HTML are shown as a single space. See [Why do multiple spaces in an HTML file show up as single spaces in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser).

To add multiple spaces in DOM use `&nbsp;` entity.

```
$('#second').append('&nbsp;'.repeat(4) + 'Help');
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mbzjedxr/2/)