# How to stop Browser from replacing multiple space by single space?

Tags: html, css

Browser is replacing Multiple space between words to the single space in html page. for e.g if my text is `'AB-DC  3'` in Browser its showing `'AB-DC 3'`. Inspect window its showing 2 spaces `'AB-DC  3'`.

you can also try out yourself. just inspect element and add multiple spaces in word of any line check.

is there any solution for this?? 
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser) answered cause, but not explaining how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you provide some code please. Are the above written with HTML itself with p tags or?

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap`. Done.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whitespace is non-significant by default, and is compacted down to a single space when rendered.

CSS can change that: `white-space: pre-wrap` will provide the default line-wrapping functionality that you would expect, plus the significant-whitespace behaviour of preformatted text. Best of both worlds!

Answer (score 9):

```
   <pre>AB          BA</pre>
```

`pre` tag will also solve your problem

Comment: This answer is the only one that works on Chrome. Save me tons of hours.

Answer (score 7):

**On the Op scenario**:
Use `white-space:pre;` (no wrap except at `<br>`) or `white-space:pre-wrap;` (wrap when needed).

*Example:*

```css
body{
  margin: 0;  
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#a {
  white-space:pre;
  background: gold;
}

#b {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id=a>This  is   some Text  writen  on here as   example.<br> Here's    a  second  sentence after the line-break .</div>
<div id=b>This  is   some Text  writen  on here as   example.<br> Here's    a  second  sentence after the line-break .</div>
```

**Single White spaces**:
Sometimes you need to use single spaces, like at the start of a sentence (when it is ignored). In situations like this, the best choice is to use `&nbsp;` instead.

*Example:*

```css
p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: tomato;  
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: greenyellow;  
}
```

```html
<p> content</p>
<p>&nbsp;content</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you give so many spaces in html it is of no use because browser will consider only one you have to use space entity `&nbsp;` the no. of times you type this entity browser will so that much spaces

**HTML:**

```
<p>He&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;llo</p>
```

It will show exact 4 spaces in the work

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/zrqrfw98/

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not the same thing as a space. You will lose the ability to wrap text on multiple lines because it is, as its name suggests, non-breaking space.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid changing your style of display.
Better to use style:

```
<style>
    { white-space: pre;}
</style>
```