# How to add spaces between two words using html?

Tags: html

Suppose I have word Abhishek Mane
I want to make this as follows
Abhishek_____________________________                        Mane. Underscore(_) indicates spaces that i want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Browser from replacing multiple space by single space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259826/how-to-stop-browser-from-replacing-multiple-space-by-single-space)

Answer (score 2):

just use the pre tag

```html
<div class="wrap">
<pre>
 Abhishek               Mane</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three different ways to achieve this:

**1. Margins**

You could put each word into its own `span`, and then give the first word a `margin-right` to add some space between the two.

```css
.first-word {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="first-word">Abhishek</span> <span>Mane</span>
```

**2. Forced spaces**

Alternatively, you can force spaces using `&#160;`.

```html
Abishnek&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Mane
```

A very similar thing can be achieved with `&nbsp`.

```html
Abishnek&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mane
```

**3. The `pre` tag**

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <pre>Abhishek               Mane</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't support normal spaces more than one. Then you have to add `&nbsp;` for multiple spaces. But it is bit longer

```html
Abhishek &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mane
```

Answer (score 0):

the HTML

```
 Abhishek <a class="tab">Mane </a>
```

CSS

```
.tab {
    margin-left: 2.5em
   }
```