# Selenium Python include quote in string is throwing error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am verifying if some text is present in my element.  The text includes a quote in the string.  My method is asserting False.  I am expecting it to be True because the text is there on the GUI.

I am not including the quote properly in the string.  What is the correct syntax please?

When i inspect the code using the debugger it says:

```
overwritten_element.text = {unicode} u'One or more reports use the \\'default\\'prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?
```

My method is:

```
def is_save_overwrite_dialog_displayed(self): 
        overwritten_element = self.get_element(By.ID, 'message_dialog_question_content')
        return overwritten_element.text == r"One or more reports use the 'default' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?"
```

The string with the quote is:
One or more reports use the 'default' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?

I have tried

```
r"One or more reports use the 'default' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you` wish to continue?"
```

and I have tried:

```
r"One or more reports use the \\'default\\' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?"
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="message_dialog_question_content">
<div>One or more reports use the 'default' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?</div>
</div>
```

get_element

```
# returns the element if found
def get_element(self, how, what):
    # params how: By locator type
    # params what: locator value
    try:
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print what
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        screenshot_name = how + what + get_datetime_now() # create screenshot name of the name of the element + locator + todays date time.  This way the screenshot name will be unique and be able to save
        self.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)
        raise
    return element
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Is this double space before the `Do` intentional?

Comment: What is the exact value of `overwritten_element.text`?

Comment: When i inspect the html it has a double space before the Do

Comment: I have walked through the code, put a break point at overwritten_element.text.  The value shows overwritten_element.text = {unicode} u'One or more reports use the \\'default\\'prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?

Comment: Could you execute `" ".join(hex(ord(c)) for c in "your text")` on both strings and tell the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having created a similar test it reveals the problem is not with the quotes but with the double space. [Spaces in HTML are compacted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser)

```
from splinter import Browser


def test_dummy():
    with Browser() as browser:
        browser.visit("http://localhost:8888/index.html")
        elem = browser.find_by_id("message_dialog_question_content")

        compare = r"One or more reports use the 'default' prefix and will be overwritten.  Do you wish to continue?"
        print "length of elem : {}, length of compare : {}".format(len(elem.text), len(compare))

        assert elem.text == compare
```

The above test outputs,

```
>       assert elem.text == compare
E       assert 'One or more ... to continue?' == 'One or more r... to continue?'
E         Skipping 60 identical leading characters in diff, use -v to show
E         - rwritten. Do you wish to continue?
E         + rwritten.  Do you wish to continue?
E         ?           +
---------- Captured stdout call ----------
length of elem : 94, length of compare : 95
```