# What was the design decision for not allowing multiple spaces & new lines in HTML?

Tags: html, whitespace

In HTML, this:

```
<p>Hel     lo</p>
```

is the same as:

```
<p>Hel lo</p>
```

and this:

```
<p>Hel



 lo</p>
```

is the same as:

```
<p>Hel

lo</p>
```

What was the design reasoning for this?

Comment: You can design your text, using `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware. I'm just wondering about the design decision for this not being the default behaviour.

Comment: If not, then you can't format your code and can't have it with your set of spaces and tabs. A similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser

Comment: I moved my answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser/45451580#45451580

Answer (score 0):

Multiple spaces normally created by the <kbd>space</kbd>, the <kbd>tab</kbd> key and <kbd>return</kbd> key are all ignored when you write code. HTML just interprets them all as whitespace between words, and displays a single space.

You still can add whitespace by insert a non-breaking space like `&nbsp;` or `&#160`.