# template literals is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, template-literals

I have my code as below. template literals not creating multiline string in span tag, where as it is creating multiline in console.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class MyApp extends Component {

    render() {

        console.log(`string text line 1
        string text line 2`);

        let test = `dfas dss
        sdassas`;

        return (
            <span>{test}</span>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyApp />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Comment: For HTML that is one space only. Your output is HTML

Comment: The string is multiline, you can see it if you use a `<pre></pre>` or `white-space: pre;` HTML collapses all whitespace into a single space for display purposes, unless instructed otherwise

Answer (score 5):

HTML collapses whitespace into a single space. See [Why does HTML require that multiple spaces show up as a single space in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-does-html-require-that-multiple-spaces-show-up-as-a-single-space-in-the-brow)

The easiest solution would be to tell that span that [it should not collapse whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

The following snippet shows you that this is not related to React, and how to display newlines in HTML

```html
<h2>Using white-space: pre</h2>
<span style="white-space: pre">       
    
    Hello this
    
    has new lines
</span>
    
<h2>Collapsing white space</h2>
<span>
    
    Hello this
    
    has new lines
    
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

When using JSX this is what solved it for me:

```
  <span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }}>
      {`
          Some
          multiline
          text
      `}
  </span>
```