# Whitespaces in between words should NOT reduced to 1 in php

Tags: php, html

I have a textfield in html. I catch data from the textfield using $_POST in php and I echo it. Whenever I echo, it automatically reduces multiple whitespaces in between words in a single whitespace. However, I did not use any trim like functions or any other functions just simple $_POST echo. I need the text AS IT IS. No reduction of whitespaces. Even in the stackoverflow, while I am writing this question I tried to put some example. But, even here extra whitespaces have been reduced to one whitespace. How to do this? TIA

Comment: That is HTML. Use `<pre>` tag

Comment: That is how browsers have always render multiple whitespaces. Encode them as entities. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-does-html-require-that-multiple-spaces-show-up-as-a-single-space-in-the-brow is a good dup

Comment: That's how they are rendered but you still have your white spaces. use urlencode({string}); and you will see + where the white spaces were rendered out

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, just use `<pre>` tag.