# What is the equivalent of &nbsp; in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, select

`SPACE()` function of SQL Server works in SQL but when select query comes to browser white space is collapsed. What is the correct representation for `&nbsp;` in SQL so that white space is kept in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do not want to do that kind of manipulation in the SQL query ; it is cleaner to let your web application format the data properly before outputing it to the user (the real solution for that dependends on the software language you use in your web app).

But of you really want to do that in SQL, just replace the `SPACE()` function in your sql query with `'&nbsp;'`, and it should appear just like that in the query result...

Comment: it is not clear for me about the purpose of SPACE if not work on browser as expected?

Comment: what i want is to concatenate two columns and put them apart little distance

Comment: there should be some way. i achieved this sometimes ago but now forget

Comment: That's just the way HTML works... There's a distinction between how HTML is formatted and how it should be rendered. Consecutive spaces are compacted in HTML, line breaks are ignored, and so on. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-does-html-require-that-multiple-spaces-show-up-as-a-single-space-in-the-brow