# How can I display more than one blank space in material UI select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI select but it's not displaying strings with multiple blank spaces as they are on the array, instead is using only one space, how can I remove this feature.

Ex: The string "Hello       World" is been display as "Hello World" but I need to display the string as it is inside the select

Answer (score 3):

> how can I remove this feature?

Actually, it has nothing to do with `ReactJS` or `MaterialUI`.
It's the way how `HTML` works. The HTML specifications stated to ignore excess whitespace.
But still if for some reason you wanted to have extra spaces in your string then there are a few workarounds as below -

1. You can use `&nbsp` instead of space in your HTML/string as shown below for Material UI `MenuItem`

```
<MenuItem value={22}>Twenty &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Two</MenuItem>
```

2. You can also use the `<pre>` HTML tag around your string or you can also do it with the `CSS` property `white-space: pre;`

```
<MenuItem style={{ whiteSpace: "pre" }} value={22} >Twenty    Two</MenuItem>
```

> white-space: pre;
> This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.

References -

- [Why does HTML require that multiple spaces show up as a single space in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433493/12541413)
- [White space: the 'white-space' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop)
- [9.1 White space](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1)
- [`<pre>` html tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)